# figures and sub figures are too wide in a row to see in the document

Tags: tables, floats, pdftex, lyx, subfloats

[image: See the first image, only 4 plots are shown, the 5th one is going out of the page, the second image is the table which is also not properly fitted into the document]I am facing an issue of floated figures and their sub figures and tables adjustment in the compiled document... They get out of the document and can't be seen when it is compiled. kindly help!

Comment: Please add a minimal working example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: For more information, please see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: The only specific advice I can give from the information given, is to reduce the width of the *Launch time ...* column. I suggest changing the header row to just *Launch*. If that isn't obvious enough, explain further in the caption. Alternatively, you could set a specific width for the column, thereby enabling line breaking.

Comment: Thanks a lot and how about the figure?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very general, so it is impossible to give specific answer. I summarize advice given by Torbjorn, and add tow examples for figures:
[image]

The code for above picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}% for tables
    \usepackage{ragged2e}% for smart right adjusting text in table
    \usepackage{graphicx}% for figures
    \usepackage{caption}% for captions
    \usepackage{subfig}% for sub figures

    \usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}% for dummy text in table

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
    \hline
year    &   Online Social Networks  \\
    \hline
1997    &   SixDegrees              \\
    \hline
1998    &   \kant[2]              \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,% limit table width to text width    
                     height=2cm]{example-image}
    \caption{My figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\subfloat[my first subfigure]%
{
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,% limited table width to desired fraction of textwidth
                     height=2cm]{example-image}
}\hfill
\subfloat[my second subfigure]%
{
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,% limite table width to desired fraction of textwidth
                     height=2cm]{example-image}
}    
\caption{My figure with two sub figures}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

In given MWE I didn't bother with table caption and coloring of rows (you didn't mentioned any problems about them). I select `tabularx` since with it you can limit table width to desired width, for example to `\textwidth` and enables multi line text in cells.

Comment: You mean I have to write a code under source pan for setting the width for tables or figures? Sorry, I am Newbie and not much trained for this stuff... Kindly help.

Comment: @faiza, your question is to general to give you good answer. Mostly I', guessing what is your problem. I do not know anything about your pictures even how you like to present. If their width are smaller as text width and their size is o.k. for you, then you not need to declare size of picture. Contrary, if pictures are wider then text width, then you need to limit them to text size. Otherwise they will protrude out of text. I suggest you to upgrade your question with code, which you write so far. With it people on SE will see what is problem and can help you.